# #openserver#пустаястраница

Tags: openserver

Здравствуйте. Установил openserver в качестве веб-сервера для просмотра веб-страницы, которую сделал. Но при вводе локального ip в строку браузера(chrome) выходит только пустая страница.Порты проверял, host-файл открыт на запись, не знаю что можно сделать. Может кто сталкивался уже с данной проблемой.Вот скрины настройки и логов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем корневой папкой домен**ов** ты сделал domains\mysite?  надо скорее оставить только `domains`, но в этой папке сделать папку `mysite` в которой будет скрипт.

Comment: у меня все так и есть. я делал просто domains, но все равно не помогло. с чем это еще может быть связано?